# Nodes Getting added automatically on Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have setup a elasticsearch cluster on AWS.I have setup three UBUNTU instances named :
elasticsearch1, elasticsearch2, elasticsearch3

I have used the [Elasticsearch Cloud AWS](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws) plugin for configuration and node discovery.

It should ideally show Three nodes but when i run :

```
curl -XGET 'http://172.30.0.17:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
```

I get :

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "LogstashCluster",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 5,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 5,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

The Master Node which is elasticsearch1 has created 3 nodes :

[image]

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Are you using docker? If not, what do you get when you run `ps aux | grep elasticsearch | wc -l` on elasticsearch1?

Comment: I am not using docker , if i run the command mentioned above i get 4

Comment: How do you start your node? is it possible that you have started it multiple times without stopping it first?

Comment: No started it once ,though restarted it a couple of times, maybe this is causing the issue ,but ideally it should not

Comment: Indeed, you restart script might not have stopped the instance properly, and started a new instance on each run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are saying you get the output of ps aux | grep elasticsearch | wc -l on your master server(172.30.0.17) as 4, it is clear that multiple instances of elasticsearch instance is running on your master. One more way to verify this by checking tcp ports opened by java. By default elasticsearch listen on two ports i.e., 9200 and 9300. You can use below command to check the list of running tcp ports

netstat -ntlp | awk '/[j]ava/'

If you get more than two ports opened by java then you have got more than one instances of elasticsearch is running. Here I am assuming that you are running only elastcisearch on that server which is using java.

To fix the issue perform following steps

1. Kill all the elasticsearch instance on the master using following command

ps auxw | awk '/[e]lasticsearch/ && /[j]ava/{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

2. Check if the above command succeeded using below command. You should not get any output

ps auxw | awk '/[e]lasticsearch/ && /[j]ava/{print $2}'

3. Start the elasticsearch service again using below command. I am assuming you have already created a service for starting elasticsearch

service elasticsearch start

4. Now again verify your running elasticsearch service using below commands

ps auxw | awk '/[e]lasticsearch/ && /[j]ava/' | wc -l #You should get output as 1

netstat -ntlp | awk '/[j]ava/' | wc -l # You should get output as 2